# Java Bytecode variable assigement

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have a piece of Bytecode here:

```
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_4);
mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 2);
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitInsn(DUP_X1);
mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 1);
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTFIELD, "a/a/lb", "O", "I");
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTFIELD, "a/a/lb", "Y", "I");
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTFIELD, "a/a/lb", "S", "I");
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTFIELD, "a/a/lb", "o", "I");
```

As you can see there are 4 variables.
How do I know which local variable is being assigned to each variable?

Comment: You look at the LocalVariableTable. That's what it's for.

Comment: Are you asking how do you know which variable is assigned to those fields? If so it's a simple matter of keeping track of what value is on the top of the stack. Read it through and when you get to the a PUTFIELD, assume it's taking the top value. The next PUTFIELD will take the new top value, and so on and so forth.